# Different behavior of sequential API and functional API for tensorflow embedding

Tags: tensorflow, keras

When I tried using Sequential API and Functional API in Tensorflow to apply the same simple embedding function, I see different result.

The result is as follows:

---

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers

inputs = np.random.randint(0, 99, [32, 100, 1])
myLayer = layers.Embedding(input_dim = 100, output_dim = 8)

# Sequential API
sm = keras.Sequential()
sm.add(myLayer)
sm_out = sm(inputs)  
sm_out.shape         # Shape of sm_out is: TensorShape([32, 100, 8])

# Functional API
fm_out = myLayer(inputs)
fm_out.shape         # Shape of fm_out is: TensorShape([32, 100, 1, 8])
```

---

Is it intended or a bug?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your second call is not a functional API call. You need to wrap your layer output (with a `tf.keras.layers.Input`) in a `tf.keras.models.Model` for this to be a functional API call.

Secondly, when you're calling the sequential model, it is smart enough to detect that last dimension is 1 and ignore that when looking up embeddings (I'm not sure where exactly this is handled, maybe someone else can point to). So when you pass in a tensor of `[32, 100, 1]`, what the embedding layer really sees is a `[32, 100]` sized array. This, after the look up, gets converted to a `[32, 100, 8]` sized tensor.

In your second call, when calling the model directly, it doesn't do this. So it simply converts the `[32, 100, 1]` sized input to a `[32, 100, 1, 8]` sized input.

You can get the same result from both these methods if you set your `inputs` shape to `[32, 100]` or `[32, 100, 2]` (last dimension != 1).

I guess the lesson here is always use the `input_shape` argument (to the first layer of the `Sequential` model) to prevent such unexpected behaviors.